# Is there a natural_sort_by method for Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of files with a bunch of attributes. One of the attributes is the file name which is how I would like to sort the list. However, the list goes something like this: filename 1, filename 2, filename 10, filename 20.

The ruby sort_by method produces this:

```
files = files.sort_by { |file| file.name }
=> [filename 1, filename 10, filename 2, filename 20]
```

I would like a more human readable list like filename 1, filename 2, filename 10, filename 20

I found the [natural_sort](http://naturalsort.rubyforge.org) gem but it seems to only work like the sort method. I need something where I can specify what to sort the array by.

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as files are always named `"file #"`, you could do

`files.sort_by{|f| f.name.split(" ")[1].to_i }`

This splits on the space, and grabs the number to do the sorting.

Comment: [1] returns the second item of the array returned by split, in this case, the number.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `.last` instead of `[1]`, so `files.sort_by{|f| f.name.split(" ").last.to_i }`

Comment: Also, alternatively, `split` assumes whitespace as the pattern to split on, so `files.sort_by{|f| f.name.split.last.to_i }` will work as well. Just to tidy things up a bit :)

Comment: I used the .last method since there are a number of spacing breaks in the filenames.

Comment: no problem, keep in mind that this method might not be the best if `'filename'` is not always what files start with, since it strictly sorts on the numbers, so "awesomefile 50" will appear after "zoo file 1".

Comment: Right. I have other sorting criteria as well but I just put up the basic example to understand the principles. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

Here's another take on a "natural" sort method:

```
class String
  def naturalized
    scan(/[^\d\.]+|[\d\.]+/).collect { |f| f.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/) ? f.to_f : f }
  end
end
```

This converts something like `"Filename 10"` into a simple array with floats in place of numbers `[ "Filename", 10.0 ]`

You can use this on your list:

```
files.sort_by! { |file| file.name.to_s.naturalized }
```

This has the advantage of working on arbitrary numbers in unpredictable positions. The paranoid `.to_s` call in that block is to ensure that there is a string and not an inadvertent `nil` when sorting.

Comment: Wow thats magic.  In my use case, identifiers may be separated by ".". Thus I remove the two '\.' in the regexp used in scan(). I don't think this could break anything.

Comment: It will mean that any values with a decimal place will be interpreted as separate numbers. 10.2 will come after 10.1 but before 10.11.

Comment: Right, I had to remove the \.'s (and the third one!) as well, else 3.3 and 3.25 sorted wrong.  So:  

scan(/[^\d]+|[\d]+/).collect { |i| i.match(/\d+/) ? i.to_i : i }

Comment: And then float seemed like the wrong thing to convert the words to.  So:  

scan(/[^\d]+|[\d]+/).collect { |w| w.match(/\d+/) ? w.to_i : w }

Comment: If you don't want whitespace you could add `\s` to the first regex matcher exclude to be like: `irb(main):021:0> "Filename 10".scan(/[^\s\d\.]+|[\d\.]+/)` produces `=> ["Filename", "10"]`. Otherwise I see `irb(main):020:0> "Filename 10".scan(/[^\d\.]+|[\d\.]+/)` produces `=> ["Filename ", "10"]` (notice the space after "Filename")

Answer (score 20):

generic answer for strings natural sort

```
array.sort_by {|e| e.split(/(\d+)/).map {|a| a =~ /\d+/ ? a.to_i : a }}
```

Comment: This fails on simple arrays like `["a1", "aa" ]` because `[ "a", 1 ] <=> [ "a", "a" ]` returns nil, and `sort_by` does not like that. (I'm not sure why that's returning nil.)

Comment: supposed to be \d+, my bad

Answer (score 9):

I've created a [natural sort gem](https://github.com/public-law/naturally). It can sort by an attribute like this:

```
# Sort an array of objects by the 'number' attribute
Thing = Struct.new(:number, :name)
objects = [
  Thing.new('1.1', 'color'),
  Thing.new('1.2', 'size'),
  Thing.new('1.1.1', 'opacity'),
  Thing.new('1.1.2', 'lightness'),
  Thing.new('1.10', 'hardness'),
  Thing.new('2.1', 'weight'),
  Thing.new('1.3', 'shape')
  ]
Naturally.sort_by(objects, :number)

# => [#<struct Thing number="1.1", name="color">,
      #<struct Thing number="1.1.1", name="opacity">,
      #<struct Thing number="1.1.2", name="lightness">,
      #<struct Thing number="1.2", name="size">,
      #<struct Thing number="1.3", name="shape">,
      #<struct Thing number="1.10", name="hardness">,
      #<struct Thing number="2.1", name="weight">]
```

Comment: Great gem, btw! I must have missed this because I created an Answer suggesting your gem. Just seeing this now. I'll leave my answer so we have better saturation but well done on this.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### [Natural Sort gem](https://github.com/rwz/natural_sort).

#### Install

`gem "natural_sort"`

#### Usage

```
list = ["a10", "a", "a20", "a1b", "a1a", "a2", "a0", "a1"]
list.sort(&NaturalSort) # => ["a", "a0", "a1", "a1a", "a1b", "a2", "a10", "a20"]
```

Comment: Damn, coming back to this and this is still very much the way to go. Excellent little gem for naturally sorting things.

Answer (score 0):

```
array.sort_by{|x| ( x.class == Array ? x.join(" ") : x.to_s ).split(/(\d+)/).map{|x| x.to_s.strip }.select{|x| x.to_s != "" }.map{|x| x =~ /\d+/ ? x.to_s.rjust(30) : x }}
```

This can compare arrays by arrays in the sort_by method even if the type of the matching items differ. Even if there are deeper nested arrays. Example:

```
[ "3  a   22", "b  22     1", "   b  5  ", [11, 2, [4, 5]] ] #=>
[ "3  a   22", [11, 2, [4, 5]], "   b  5  ", "b  22     1" ]
```

The point here is that during the sort if an item is a nested array then we convert it to a string beforehand. And if parts of the string contain digits only then we do not convert them to numeric values but instead extend them with spaces, like:

```
30 #=> "                         30"
```

This way all objects will be compatible strings and the sorting will be able to compare them resulting in a numeric sort if the matching objects at their positions are numbers only.

Answer (score -3):

It is sorting correctly. The problem here is that the names aren't good to sort the way you want. In means of string, 10 comes before 2 and 21 comes before 5.

If you want it to sort it like it was numbers, you have 2 approaches:

1 - Change all your listings to add a leading 0 before numbers with just one digit.

2 - Do as William suggested, aplit the name, transform the string to integer and sort by it.

I would recommend option 1 since the second rely on the padronization of the names.