# "natural" sort an array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, natural-sort

There are workable answers for [sorting an array of hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483889/in-ruby-how-sort-an-array-of-hashes) and for [natural sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078906/is-there-a-natural-sort-by-method-for-ruby), but what is the best way to do both at once?

```
my_array = [ {"id":"some-server-1","foo":"bar"},{"id":"some-server-2","foo":"bat"},{"id":"some-server-10","foo":"baz"} ]
```

I would like to sort on "id" such that the final ordering is:

```
some-server-1
some-server-2
some-server-10
```

I feel like there must be a clever and efficient way to do this, though personally I don't need to break any speed records and will only be sorting a few hundred items. Can I implement a comparison function in sort_by?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your `my_array` is JavaScript/JSON so I'll assume that you really have this:

```
my_array = [
    {"id" => "some-server-1",  "foo" => "bar"},
    {"id" => "some-server-2",  "foo" => "bat"},
    {"id" => "some-server-10", "foo" => "baz"}
]
```

Then you just need to [`sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001481) the numeric suffix of the `'id'` values:

```
my_array.sort_by { |e| e['id'].sub(/^some-server-/, '').to_i }
```

If the "some-server-" prefixes aren't always "some-server-" then you could try something like this:

```
my_array.sort_by { |e| e['id'].scan(/\D+|\d+/).map { |x| x =~ /\d/ ? x.to_i : x } }
```

That would split the `'id'` values into numeric and non-numeric pieces, convert the numeric pieces to integers, and then compare the mixed string/integers arrays using the Array [`<=>` operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000266) (which compares component-wise); this will work as long as the numeric and non-numeric components always match up. This approach would handle this:

```
my_array = [
    {"id" => "some-server-1", "foo" => "bar"},
    {"id" => "xxx-10",        "foo" => "baz"}
]
```

but not this:

```
my_array = [
    {"id" => "11-pancakes-23", "foo" => "baz"},
    {"id" => "some-server-1",  "foo" => "bar"}
]
```

If you need to handle this last case then you'd need to compare the arrays entry-by-entry by hand and adjust the comparison based on what you have. You could still get some of the advantages of the `sort_by` [Schwartzian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz) [Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_Transform) with something like this (not very well tested code):

```
class NaturalCmp
    include Comparable
    attr_accessor :chunks

    def initialize(s)
        @chunks = s.scan(/\D+|\d+/).map { |x| x =~ /\d/ ? x.to_i : x }
    end

    def <=>(other)
        i = 0
        @chunks.inject(0) do |cmp, e|
            oe = other.chunks[i]
            i += 1
            if(cmp == 0)
                cmp = e.class == oe.class \
                    ? e      <=> oe \
                    : e.to_s <=> oe.to_s
            end
            cmp
        end
    end
end

my_array.sort_by { |e| NaturalCmp.new(e['id']) }
```

The basic idea here is to push the comparison noise off to another class to keep the `sort_by` from degenerating into an incomprehensible mess. Then we use the same scanning as before to break the strings into pieces and implement the array `<=>` comparator by hand. If we have two things of the same class then we let that class's `<=>` deal with it otherwise we force both components to String and compare them as such. And we only care about the first non-0 result.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. What if not every prefix is "some-server"?

Comment: This totally worked in my case and got me thinking the right way.

Comment: @Ben: I took it to the next step if you're interested, I didn't want to leave the job half done.

Comment: I haven't tried the code yet, but it's clear and pretty cool. Bookmarking this one. =)

Answer (score 1):

@mu gives a more than adequate answer for my case, but I also figured out the syntax for introducing arbitrary comparisons:

```
def compare_ids(a,b)
  # Whatever code you want here
  # Return -1, 0, or 1
end

sorted_array = my_array.sort { |a,b| compare_ids(a["id"],b["id"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you are sorting on the `id` field, you could try this:

```
my_array.sort { |a,b| a["id"].to_i <=> b["id"].to_i }
```

Comment: I think that would do an alphabetic sort, no? So 1, 10, 2?

Comment: I think the change still has the same issue. The string will need to be split somehow and ordered first by alphabetic sort, then by numeric sort.