# Store files in natural sort filename with paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Paperclip is generating my files and appending to its filename an index, but when stored to db it is sorted not the way i want (image below). Note that is not a natural sort (1,10,2,3,4,5...) instead of (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10..).

What am i have to do? Nedd some kind of "**before_create**" to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to override sorting via [default_sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393687/how-do-i-set-a-default-sort-order-for-a-rails-model) in your model.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078906/is-there-a-natural-sort-by-method-for-ruby) covers how to do a natural sort in Ruby.

Comment: i would prefer if the files were stored in natural sort already =/